# Using the Installer and clicking Upgrade - Are they the same?

Tags: upgrade, live-cd

I'm currently using 11.10.

I have a downloaded copy of 12.04 on CD.

Question: Is it the same if I hit the UPGRADE button on the update manager, or install 12.04 through the CD? Will I lose my work/settings/installed apps (LAMP, Lazarus, etc) by either method? I know if I boot from the CD and install, I'll most certainly lose everything... But my question is will this happen even if I run the CD while on Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this thread answer your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120929/upgrade-the-distribution-or-reinstall-the-system/120934

Comment: @jippie Thanks for taking the time... From that link I understand that clicking UPGRADE will not cause data loss. Now back to my question - will it be the same if I run the CD while running Ubuntu, or will it run as a fresh installation? Thanks again!

Comment: It **should** not cause data loss. Always make backups. Not sure what exact CD you are referring to.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Comment: @izx I have accepted the answer a long time ago... I there something I missed? Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is will this happen even if I run the CD while on Ubuntu?

You should understand that the Ubuntu Live-CDs (which most people download) do NOT contain the .deb packages that are used for an upgrade; instead, they contain the entire filesystem in compressed form, so that it can be used both for the LiveCD, and to perform a new installation (the filesystem is simply copied to the hard disk in that case).

If you have decent internet access, it is HIGHLY recommended to go the upgrade route. If you don't, maybe you can get your hands on the alternate CD? That does have the regular deb packages/repository, and you could *conceivably* use `apt-cdrom` to add it to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as a local repository and use it for the upgrade.