# Should I upgrade all the applications with Ubuntu's reinstall/upgrade?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, upgrade, reinstall, 18.04

This should be an easy question but since it is my first experience with this I thought I'll be better off asking some questions:

1. Is upgrading Ubuntu the exact same as reinstalling the new version. I know there are some answers, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32837/is-it-better-to-upgrade-through-the-update-manager-or-re-install-from-scratch) contradicting [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120929/upgrade-the-distribution-or-reinstall-the-system), hopefully someone knowledgeable could make a clear cut.
2. Be it upgrade, should I upgrade all the other installed applications in order for them to work? if yes, would the upgrade be available immediately after the release of the new Ubuntu?
3. Be it reinstall, how long would it take to have packages ready for install for the new version of Ubuntu?

I don't mind re-configuring and reinstalling the apps if reinstalling Ubuntu, but it could be better if I don't if both reinstalling and upgrading are no different.

Comment: When 18.04 is releases read the upgrade instruction s and release notes. Yes it updates all apps. Fresh install is cleaner but upgrades typically work

Comment: The HWE stack is a consideration: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack